# Are there any equivalent for groovy """ in python?

Tags: python, file

I'm very new to python. I'm from groovy and I use `""""` to write some text into files the way I wish.

Are there any equivalent way in python to?

Note that I want to create a file that has more than 20 lines. So I need some easy and elegant way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Groovy's triple-quote syntax for multi-line strings was actually borrowed from Python, so if that's all you're looking for, you're done. If you want `"` interpolation (which works with both `"` and `"""` in Groovy), that was borrowed from sh, and Python doesn't do it, so you need to use one of the alternatives. Which are you after?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not clear what exactly you're asking about.

The ability to use `'''` or `"""` for multi-line strings in Groovy was borrowed directly from Python, so of course you can do the exact same thing in Python.

However, the ability to use `"` or `"""` for interpolated strings in Groovy was borrowed from sh, and Python does not have the same feature. In Python, `'` and `"` strings are identical, and neither does interpolation.

The idiomatic Python alternative is [`format`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings). This is a method on the `str` and `unicode` classes, which you use like this:

```
s = """This is a string with a {variable} to fill in.
Here's a {second} one
""".format(variable="field", second="'nother")
```

If you write that to a file, you'll get this:

```
This is a string with a field to fill in.
Here's a 'nother one
```

There are plenty of variations. If you want to pass arguments by position instead of name, you can use `{0}` instead of `{variable}`—or, for simple cases where they're inserted in order, just use `{}` (but be careful with i18n). You can also put formatting information in, e.g., to print the `repr` (sort of "what you would type to get this value") instead of the `str` (a human-readable representation). Read the docs linked above for details.

Python also has an older mechanism, which is being gradually phased out, that uses the [`%` operator](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting) and a format spec based on, but pretty different from, C-style `printf`. For example:

```
s = """This is a string with a %(variable)s to fill in.
Here's a %(second)s one
""" % {"variable": "field", "second": "'nother"}
```

Again, there are plenty of variations available; again, read the docs linked above for details. But really, you only want to use this if you're dealing with a lot of old code, or translating from `printf` or Windows-style or similar formats, or need to run on Python 2.5 or earlier.

If none of this is sufficient for you, there are 69,105 modules on [PyPI](http://pypi.python.org/pypi) (and recipes on ActiveState, etc.) for doing everything from as-close-to-perl-as-possible interpolation to templating HTML pages.

Answer (score 2):

Python supports `"""` for escaping multi-line strings. Variable substitution is not immediately available, however.

```
multi_line_variable = """This
Is   
The
Coolest
Ever."""
```

If you need variable substitution, you can use Python's `printf` formatting support or use a templating library like Jinja or the Django templating language.

Python 'printf' formatting:

```
>>> echo """Massive %s!""".format("string")
"Massive string!"
```

Comment: First, it's better to use the modern [`format`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings) method than the old-style [`%` operator](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting). Second, as written, the answer sounds like it's suggesting a function called `printf`, which doesn't exist, rather than the `%` operator, and it's a little misleading to call it "`printf` formatting support", because it's different enough from `printf` to lead to confusion.

Answer (score 1):

```
f = open(name_of_file, 'w')
f.writelines(list_of_lines_to_write)
f.close()
```

Or instead of `writelines()`, use `f.write("""text_to_write_to_file""")`

Comment: `writelines` is a bit mis-leading as it won't actually write EOLs... (although generally, I agree that a list of "lines" is generally more uesful/readable than a multi-line string)